Pass data from modal view to parent view
Im making an video app and im trying to pass data from list modal view to parent list.
The list view work when i set the static url to fetcher.
Im trying to change json url from modal view to parent and parse data to list view, fetcher working good and right when i see on print log but the list view doesnt update the content.
VideoView.swift
public class VideoFetcher: ObservableObject {

    @Published var videos = [Video]()
/*
    init(){
        load(videoURL: URL(string: "http://192.168.1.168:8080/category/shorts/vegie-elite.json")!)
    }
*/
    func load(videoURL: URL) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: videoURL) {(data,response,error) in
            do {
                if let d = data {
                    let decodedLists = try JSONDecoder().decode([Video].self, from: d)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.videos = decodedLists
                        print(decodedLists)
                    }
                }else {
                    print("No Data")
                }
            } catch {
                print (error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

and here is the list which show the content

struct VideoView: View {
 //   @State private var isPresented = false
    @State private var showingSheet = false
    @ObservedObject var fetcher = VideoFetcher()
    
    @State var vURL: String

    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List (fetcher.videos) { video in
                NavigationLink(destination: VideoPlayerLive(videoLink: video.v1080p)
                    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                    .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
                ) {
                    HStack {
                        WebImage(url: URL(string: video.image)) { image in
                            image.resizable() // Control layout like SwiftUI.AsyncImage, you must use this modifier or the view will use the image bitmap size
                            
                        } placeholder: {
                            Rectangle().foregroundColor(Color("color.background.cell"))
                        }
                        // Supports options and context, like `.delayPlaceholder` to show placeholder only when error
                        .onSuccess { image, data, cacheType in
                            // Success
                            // Note: Data exist only when queried from disk cache or network. Use `.queryMemoryData` if you really need data
                        }
                        .indicator(.activity) // Activity Indicator
                        .transition(.fade(duration: 0.5)) // Fade Transition with duration
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                        
                        VStack (alignment: .leading)  {
                            Spacer()
                            Text(video.name)
                                .font(.system(size: 18))
                                .foregroundColor(Color("color.text.orange"))
                            Spacer()
                            Text(video.released)
                                .font(.system(size: 13))
                                .foregroundColor(Color("color.text.gray"))
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
 
            .refreshable {
                fetcher.load(videoURL: URL(string: vURL)!)
                fetcher.objectWillChange.send()
            }    
              
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button {
                        showingSheet.toggle()
                    }label: {
                        Image(systemName: "list.bullet")
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
                        VideoCategory()
                    }
                }
                           
            }
        }
        
    }
}

Here is VideoModel.swift

public struct Video: Identifiable, Codable {
    public var id: Int
    public var name: String
    public var image: String
    public var released: String
    public var v720p: String
    public var v1080p: String

    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case name = "title"
        case image = "image"
        case released = "year"
        case v720p = "v720p"
        case v1080p = "v1080p"
    }
}


and here is VideoCategory (child view with list)
var body: some View {
        @State var fileItems = FileItem.preview()
        
        NavigationStack {
            List(fileItems, children: \.children) { fileItem in
                
                if fileItem.isFolder {
                    Label(fileItem.title, systemImage: "folder.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(Color("color.text.pink"))
                    
                } else {
              //      Label(fileItem.title, systemImage: "film")
                //        .foregroundColor(Color("color.text.orange"))
                    Button {
                   //     VideoFetcher().load(videoURL: URL(string: fileItem.url)!)
                        VideoView(vURL: fileItem.url).fetcher.load(videoURL: URL(string: fileItem.url)!)
                        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    } label: {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "film")
                            Text(fileItem.title)
                                .foregroundColor(Color("color.text.orange"))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

Im tried to search solution but i cant find any same case like me.
Can anyone help me with this problem. Im new with swiftui. Thank you!

Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Normally you put the State in the parent and pass the Binding to the child so it can write to it

@malhal hi! Im trying but i dont know where to put Binding in to child view. I also tried with that but showing error so i delete the binding

This should help https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding

Note, you should use
@StateObject var fetcher = VideoFetcher() in your top most view of your hierarchy and
pass it to the other views, eg using: @ObservedObject var fetcher: VideoFetcher.
Also you should not
declare @State var fileItems = FileItem.preview() inside the body of your
VideoCategory view, move that outside of the body.
Try declaring @Binding var vURL: String in your VideoView and pass a value to it
from VideoCategory using List($fileItems, children: \.children) { $fileItem in and
VideoView(vURL: $fileItem.url)...

@workingdogsupportUkraine Hi! I have done what you write but when I put : VideoView(vURL: $fileItem.url) in CategoryView, nothing happen and it says: Result of 'VideoView' initializer is unused.

yes, you should not have VideoView(...) inside the action of a Button. Move that outside of the Button, and use for example, a @State private var showVideo ... with a if showVideo {VideoView(...)} in the body to display  it.

@workingdogsupportUkraine hi! I don't understand correctly what you mean. Can I have contact with you in discord or something like that. Thank you!

Try this approach to resolve some of your problems.
Using @StateObject private var fetcher = VideoFetcher() in your VideoView
and passing the model to VideoCategory using .environmentObject(fetcher).
Have a look at this link Managing model data in your app, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app.
Since there are many elements missing from the code, I cannot test the code,
however using this approach should get you closer to what you want to achieve.
struct VideoCategory: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var fetcher: VideoFetcher  // <--- here
    let fileItems = FileItem.preview() // <--- I assume this gives [FileItem]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(fileItems, children: \.children) { fileItem in
                if fileItem.isFolder {
                    Label(fileItem.title, systemImage: "folder.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(Color("color.text.pink"))
                } else {
                    //      Label(fileItem.title, systemImage: "film")
                    //        .foregroundColor(Color("color.text.orange"))
                    Button {
                        if let url = URL(string: fileItem.url) { // <--- here
                            fetcher.load(videoURL: url) // <--- here
                        }
                    } label: {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "film")
                            Text(fileItem.title)
                                .foregroundColor(Color("color.text.orange"))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct VideoView: View {
    @State private var showingSheet = false
    @StateObject private var fetcher = VideoFetcher()  // <--- here
    let vURL: String // <--- here, or @Binding var if need be

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List (fetcher.videos) { video in
                NavigationLink(destination: VideoPlayerLive(videoLink: video.v1080p)
                    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                    .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
                ) {
                    HStack {
                        // ......
                    }
                }
            }
            .refreshable {
                fetcher.load(videoURL: URL(string: vURL)!)
              //  fetcher.objectWillChange.send() // <--- should not have to do this
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button {
                        showingSheet.toggle()
                    }label: {
                        Image(systemName: "list.bullet")
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
                        VideoCategory()
                            .environmentObject(fetcher)  // <--- here
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

